# How can I create flask project using IntelliJ IDEA 12 Ultimate Edition?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, flask

I have `IntelliJ IDEA 12 Ultimate Edition` and I was watching [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jaFEODzG7B8) video on Youtube where they have demonstrated to create Flask using PyCharm 2.6

As far as I understand Python Plugin gives same features as PyCharm because they are built form same codebase.

How can I create a flask project with IDEA 12 Ultimate Edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Python plugin already installed, a "Flask Project" option will be available under "Python" when creating a new project.

I created a virtualenv before creating my Flask project and set it up as the project's SDK.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've recently tried the same with IDEA 2016.3.3. Installed Python plugin, Python and flask via pip; created a Flask project. Just fails silently, creating the empty directory. Was forced to install PyCharm.

Answer (score 21):

To clarify wmora's answer, in IntelliJ IDEA, installing the Python plugin is not 100% the same as having PyCharm, and the distinction is one that Jetbrains seems to have struggled with (e.g. usually documentation refers to the language-specific IDE and not to IDEA, and the menu-items/commands/etc. are not the same).

With IDEA, if the Python plugin is installed, you can create a new project and select "Python" as the language.  This may show a few additional libraries and frameworks, e.g. "Django", "Google App Engine (Python)", and "SQL Support" (???), **but notably NOT Flask**.  However, the *next screen* has the option to "Create project from template", and when checked, you should be able to select the "Flask Project" template.

And THAT's when it fails silently (per Polyakoff's comment).  The editor doesn't even open up a window.  See the bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-25666

Comment: Not yet, since 2020.1 was a disaster of a release -- none of my Elixir projects would open, so I had to roll back.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2019.1.3, built on May 28, 2019.